# Using broker authentication with ADAL library in Intune managed application

Tags: xamarin.android, adal, intune

I have searched the internet, and I think I understand every step of documentation provided by Microsoft in achieving the brokered authentication via company portal or Authenticator app.

As per documentation [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/leveraging-brokers-on-Android-and-iOS).

If I use below signature

```
public PlatformParameters(Activity callerActivity, bool useBroker)
public PlatformParameters(Activity callerActivity, bool useBroker, PromptBehavior promptBehavior)
```

and provide "true" for userBroker parameter, I am good.

My only problem is.

I have downloaded ADAL library from NuGet and I found.

Version 5.0.5 -> PlatformParameters class doesn't have this constructor signature nor it has useBroker public property, how do I supply it?

Version 4.5.1 -> Does not have it either.

I kept on searching and I found this signature available in version 3.19.8

In such case, am I suppose to use 2 years old version, is there something I am missing?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions on it.

Answer (score 0):

Fix was quite simple.
I just had to change the target framework to 8.1 from 8.0, and then I had to retarget the ADAL Nuget package.

After doing this I can use the latest version of ADAL, It has all the constructor overloads.